# How to tell if a CollectionViewCell is at the center of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollecitonView` that scrolls horizontally. I have a requirement such that when the user scrolls to the right or left, the collection view cell at the horizontal center of the screen is colored differently.  The color needs to updated as each passes through the center.

Our UICollectionView shows three `UICollectionViewCell`s at startup, so "center" is defined as the CGRect of the second `UICollectionViewCell`.

How to detect this?  Is there an event that fires at scroll end?  Also, how to tell if a CGRect rectangle is within another CGRect rectangle's bounds?

Comment: You can use `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` from `UIScrollViewDelegate` to determine the cell that will be centered.

Comment: Does the color need to update only after scrolling has finished or does it need to happen as each passes through the center? Also, is the "center" defined as a single point (CGPoint), a range (CGRect), or whatever cell happens to be nearest to the nearest point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This answer will give you rough idea about 
>   1. how to get scrollView event callback.
>   2. how to convert point or rect from one view coordinates to  another view coordinates.
>   3. how to get CollectionViewCell at certain point in CollectionView.
>
> You can change the code as per your requirement.

**1. Create a method as follow**

```
    func scrollViewDidEndScrolling(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

         let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.minY)
         let collectionViewCenterPoint = self.view.convert(centerPoint, to: collectionView)    

         if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: collectionViewCenterPoint) { 
                let collectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
                collectionViewCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
         }
    }
```

In above method we are trying to find the `CollectionViewCell` which is at the centre of the `CollectionView`. We are trying to get that `CollectionViewCell`'s indexPath and update its background color.

**2. Implement below given `ScrollViewDelegate` methods**

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         self.scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

         if !decelerate {
            self.scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
         }
    }
```

We have to call our method from these `ScrollViewDelegate` methods. These methods gets called when `collectionView` stops scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, with some minor modifications I was able to adjust your code and do exactly what I needed it to do